# Latest PHPStorm version. Have multiple projects in one window

Tags: phpstorm

Currently we are on the PHPStorm version 9.0.2.

I know it was not possible to have multiple projects in the same window (which seems weird to me as it has a 'Project' panel where you can toggle your project. This toggle functionality does not make much sense if you are only allowed to have only one project).

Do you know if it is possible to have multiple projects in one window?

Comment: We have nothing to do with phpstorm, and you'd have to ask the developers why a feature is/isn't present.

Comment: *"it has a 'Project' panel where you can toggle your project"* Can please tell where such panel is located (screenshot please)?

Comment: *"Do you know if they have implemented this functionality in the new version?"* Nothing has changed. But you can always add files from another project and display them as additional node in current project (which makes it part of current project even if files are located elsewhere on your disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know if it is possible to have multiple projects in one window?

It is still not possible to have multiple **independent** projects (with separate settings) in one window/frame.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15187 -- watch this ticker (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

1. If you want to ***add files to the project and be able to edit them*** (they become part of the actual project -- will participate in global search/replace; refactorings; vcs / deployment; checked for errors etc) -- just use **Additional Content Root** functionality (`Settings/Preferences | Project | Directories --> Add Content Root` button) -- such folder will added as additional node in Project View panel.
2. If such project/library is needed for ***reference purpose only*** (code completion) and not active editing then **External Libraries** will suffice (`Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP -> Include paths`).